# Does Lemon juice change acidic level when frozen?

Tags: lemon, juice

I used frozen lemon juice in a lemon icebox pie. It had egg yolks and sweetened condensed milk as additional ingredients. It failed to set up. Does freezing lemon juice change the acidic property?

Comment: Acidity does go down with temperature and bring temperature back up does not always bring it back up to the the prior acidity.  I don't have data on lemon juice.

Comment: @paparazzo Where d you get this information. I do not think that is accurate at all. Perceived sourness may change, but pH will not.

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars Where do you get it will not?  Google water ph versus temperature.

Comment: pH is determined by acid content. For a chemical acid like citric acid in lemon juice, low temperature will cause a veeerrryyyy slight reduction. Different for WATER, which you refer to , which is not an acid.

Comment: PH goes down but I am seeing data that acidity may not.  I am not sure.

Comment: @MarsJarsGuitars-n-Chars I said I did not have data lemon juice.  PH is the negative log of the hydrogen ion concentration.  No going to argue with you.

Comment: @paparazzo No worries. It does appear you are not clear on acidity/pH/acids, etc.. so probably shouldn't bring it up then.

Answer (score 1):

The acidity, ie. the amount of chemical acid in the juice, will not change when lemon juice is frozen. Acid would need to be neutralized by a base, or in the case of citric acid and other organic acids, very high heat.

Was the lemon juice completely thawed? If not, that could be an issue, all the juice must be liquid for the acid to be free and work on the yolks.

Perhaps there was something else happening in your recipie. If you can edit in basic proportions and method. AS I understand it an icebox pie is mixed and chilled to set, usually no cooking, like to set a custard?

Comment: It is a reach but the freeze and thaw of some of the non-water components could release and as acid or base.

Comment: @paparazzo I would kindly ask that you not just 'hypothesize.' There is no pathway for freezing to make other chemicals release acidiity.

Comment: Freeze can crack a solid and expose components.   Freeze and thaw does not always return to the same composition.